# Firebase Cloud Messaging sending messages one by one

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app where I want to send notifications to multiple users from my backend server. These notifications will contain 4 different contents, three of them will go to 3 different users, but the forth one will go to more than 1000 users, the frequency of theses messages will be 3 to 7 times a week. Is it ok to send this amount of messages one by one using the Cloud Messaging api? Or should I group the messages before sending?

I thought about creating a topic in the Cloud Messaging, and subscribe the users to it and then send a message, but I don't if it is correct to keep subscribing/unsubscribing users just to send one message.

NOTE: I've never used any push notifications service before.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Cloud Messaging infrastructure delivers billions of messages per day. The volume you're describing sounds well within reason for it.

Without knowing more about the use-case it's hard to say whether using a topic would be a better approach, so I recommend reading the documentation on [topic messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) to get a better understanding for it.